# array and curve modifiers (bezier) - distorted texture

Tags: texturing, uv

I have created a simple road using bezier curve, array and curve modifiers. As you can see on the picture some faces looks weird - a texutre is distorted. Why ? Did I do something wrong ? How to  fix that ?[image]

Comment: could you please pack the image and share the file?

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04552707576784415557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I hope my answer is accurate enough.

Your faces are projected as squares on the image in the *UV Editor*. But your faces are actually not squares, they are twisted quads. Also, in any 3D software a face is made of 2 triangles. So when Blender will map this face the UV map it will simply map 2 triangles, and it will give the following result.

[image]

If you subdivide your face a bit with some <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>, the same thing will happen, but as your faces are much smaller the effect will be much less visible.

[image]

Comment: I didn't unwrap anything, I just added a single plane object which was already unwrapped and I only used scale/translate in uv editing mode. Then that single plane object has been used with modifiers and bezier curve. But it looks like your explanation is correct.